# Confusion in BODMAS rule to evaluate $\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck with a question
$$\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)$$
We can have different approach to this problem but how are we gonna apply BODMAS here.

Comment: Division is not associative, so this expression is ambiguous.

Comment: All these BODMAS/ PEMDAS  things are nonsense.

Comment: @BokaPeer What?

Comment: Read the first comment. Students memorize this  BODMAS/ PEMDAS thing. They are not taught the "right" concept: we cannot "combine" more things together. What I mean parenthesis matters. At the very end, probably someone can be taught this nmemonic.

Comment: @Dave: It is not ambiguous at all. Subtraction is also non-associative, but I think you will agree that $6-3-7-1$ is unambiguously equal to $-5$. And division is left-to-right associative by convention, just like subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only one operator (divide), you would simply divide left to right.

Answer (score 0):

We will take from left torright.

$$\left(\frac15\right)\div\left(\frac15\right)$$

$$ =>1 $$

Now go towards right side

$$ \frac{1}{1} \div \frac{1}{5} $$

So now it is reduced to $5$.

So now finally it will become

$$ 5 \div \frac{1}{5}$$

Your final answer will come $25$.